# A few Questions about Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle

A few questions about Castle Windsor.

I have a service that looks like this:

```
public interface IMysRepository
{
    ISomeObject GetById(int id);
}

public interface IMyService
{
     ISomeObject GetById(int id);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
     MyService(IMysRepository repository)
     {
          _repository = repository;
     }


     public ISomeObject GetById(int id)
     {
          return _repository.GetById(id);
     } 

     IMysRepository _repository
}
```

I'm thinking the best thing to do is keep that in the container but not sure if I should keep it as Singleton or Transient.  The only state it keeps is the repository.  I was thinking the best way would be as a Singleton and the code looks cleaner too.  For example:

```
//Singleton version.
var service = container.Reslove<IMyService>();
var obj = IMyService.GetById(100);
```

vs

```
//Transient version.
var service = container.Reslove<IMyService>();
try
{
     var obj = IMyService.GetById(100);
}
finally
{
   container.Release(service);
}
```

Also the other thing I'm wondering is Castle thread safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually depends on how the repository is coded. Read [this article](http://igorbrejc.net/development/c/the-delicate-dance-of-transience) to understand how components of different lifestyles interact.  I always try to make my components thread-safe, stateless so I can make them singletons, it makes everything simpler.

BTW: you should try to avoid calling Resolve() as much as possible. [Don't call the container, it will call you](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/30/DontCallTheContainerItllCallYou.aspx).

And yes, Windsor is thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not completely understanding what you mean by don't use Resolve because I'm pretty much doing everything that blog says.  Also, as of right now I'm just using ADO.NET to get data from the database.  I'm thinking I should use Transient.  If you don't call .Release on a Transient you have a resource leak, correct?

Comment: @Michael: ideally you should only call Resolve and Release at root sites. About Release, in a nutshell you should release what you explicitly resolve. See http://kozmic.pl/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/ for more details.